# Printing a series of armstrong number using python is showing error

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in python and i want to create a program for printing a series of armstrong numbers for a given range. But it is showing nothing, i am unable to find out my mistake. So please look at my code and help me to find out my mistake.

```
def armstrong():
  r = int(input("Enter range :"))

  for i in range(2,r+1):
    power = len(str(i))
    temp = i
    sum = 0

    while temp>0:
      rem = temp%10
      sum = sum + rem**power
      temp = temp/10

    if sum == i:
      print(" "+i)

armstrong()
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the error message you are getting.

Comment: sorry sir, my mistake. It is not printing anything when I input 1000 in r's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` never equals `i` because `temp/10` doesn't give the answer you're expecting.

In Python 3, `15/10` is the floating-point number `1.5`, not the integer `1` as it would have been in Python 2 (or several other languages). To get floor division (the Python 2 behavior) you need to use the `//` operator, or (my preference) do both `//` and `%` at once with the built-in `divmod` function:

```
while temp>0:
  temp, rem = divmod(temp, 10)
  sum = sum + rem**power
```

With this change, you'll get a new error about how `int` and `str` can't be concatenated (I think the error is slightly different depending on version). But the fix for that one is easy: convert `i` to a string before concatenating it.

```
print(" " + str(i))
```

Comment: Thanks @trentcl for this awesome explaination, Now it is working.
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cubesum(num):
"""This functions returns a sum of the cubes of individual digits"""
r=[];s=[];sumc=0
s=list(str(num)) #converts the number into a list of string
r=list(map(int,s)) #converts the list of string into list of integers
for i in r:
    sumc=sumc+i**3
return(sumc)

def PrintArmstrong():
"""This function prints all the armstrong number from 1 to n"""
num1=int(input("enter the value of n for armstrong number search "))
for i in range(num1+1):
    if i==cubesum(i):   #checks whether i is a armstrong number. calls function cubesum()
        print("{} is a armstrong number".format(i))
```

This might help. I use two functions here. One returns the sum of the cubes of individual digits and another checks whether the numbers in a range equals its sum of its individual digits.

Answer (score 0):

This program first asks the user to enter nos of test cases, after that asks for the number to check whether it is Armstrong number or not.
It first checks that number is non-zero,If yes then

1. finds the remainder of that number.
2. finds the square of the remainder and stores in a variable "sum".
3. finds the quotient of the number entered by user.

Finally if the original number is equal to the "sum" then it is an armstrong num else not.

Here's the code:

```
t=int(input("nos of test cases"))
while t>0:
    num=int(input("enter any number = "))
    n=num
    sum=0
    while n>0:
        digit=n%10
        sum += digit ** 3
        n=n//10

    if num==sum:
        print("armstronng num")
    else:
        print("not armstrong")
    t-=1
```